# Get sibling component in Vue test utils (Vue 3, Composition API)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-test-utils

I'm currently exploring unit testing and Vue test utils particularly. I have an external library (`vue-toastification`) that shows a toast message when something occurs. I'd like to test that this toast has been shown, if an Error was thrown. But the problem is that the toast is rendered outside component's scope (in App.vue, as far as I can see), meanwhile with `.get` method we can only retrieve child components of a wrapper. So, how can I access this toast component without mounting the whole application? Maybe I should somehow use `<teleport>`?

Comment: You preferably shouldn't. vue-toastification isn't your own unit and it adds moving parts, so it needs to be mocked

Comment: I agree with Estus. It's a third library that it's not your role to unit test. I think what you want to do (check that the notification appears) can be made with cypress

Comment: @EstusFlask and Adri HM, thank you guys, you were right, excuse my silly question:)